# C char * into Objective-C NSString (or NSData?)

Tags: objective-c, c, string

I'm parsing a file byte stream in C and organising the results into `NSDictionary`s and `NSArray`s in Objective-C world via callback.

The keys of an `NSDictionary` are all instances of `NSString`. I'm converting the C character strings into `NSString`s with the `NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding` but now and again some of the keys are `nil` (even when the C character strings have one or more characters).

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding` is an extremely old and rare string encoding and is probably the wrong one to use. Your text files will generally be in either Latin-1 or UTF-8, if they originated in Western Europe or in North America. Let's assume UTF-8 for now (that's `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.) Ideally, you'd know the encoding used when writing the files, and you'd use that when reading them.

You presumably have the rest of the code correct, since you are getting strings back. It's the strings that aren't pure 7-bit ASCII that are likely giving you trouble.

Comment: `NSUTF8StringEncoding` kills about 90% of the characters. `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` doesn't seem to be killing anything. Which is good.

Comment: There are other encodings that may be appropriate.

Comment: Indeed - `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` might be what I need. Thanks very much for your help.